# Where is Visual Studio storing Publish Profiles?

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio, azure

I have a corrupted Publish profile.

I need to delete it.  My other computer is fine, so I know it is local.

I have tried:

1. Clean checkout of codebase from Git (so nothing is local in my code directories).
2. Deleting `C:/Users/<user>/AppData/Local/VisualStudio`
3. Deleting `C:/Users/<user>/AppData/Roaming/VisualStudio`
4. Full text search of Profile Name 'MunicipalAgenda' through Registry
5. Full Text search through machine.
6. Creation of a new Windows User for Visual Studio Development.

Despite all of this, VS.NET is hanging onto that corrupted Publish profile.

Honestly I am at wits' end, and my next drastic step is to do a fresh reinstall of Windows 10.  **Please help before it comes to that!!!**

[image]

Comment: Inside your project directory , there must be a folder named as Properties - inside it a xml file with extension  "your-publishprofile-.pubxml"

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Normally any publish profile store in particular project.

For that you have to look at following location.

1. Go to that project.
2. Project has special folder call Properties
3. Inside that there is a folder called PublishProfiles ( Something similar)

Comment: Strange, I have 1 profile in there, but 2 profiles at the Publish dropdown... Why is that?

Comment: @mgPePe me too, until I tried the other answer, deleting the profiles from source control explorer directly.

Comment: What if there is no folder inside the Properties folder? It keeps forcing me to publish with the ClickOnce wizard and I really need that to stop.

Answer (score 3):

I also had some difficulty in getting my profile deletions to stick ... Visual Studio (2017) doesn't seem to be able to do it from Solution Explorer.

My latest attempt is to go to Source Control Explorer, open up the /Properties/PublishProfiles folder, and delete and commit the unwanted profiles from there.  So far so good :)

Comment: Yes! Thanks for this...I kept deleting 10 publish profiles and kept having them show up still when publishing. This solution did the trick!